# How to show mapview location in listview item?

Tags: android, listview, android-mapview

I want to show list of orders with exact location of the customer in listview.[image]

Comment: I advice you to use `CardView` like list item for these purposes.

Comment: use static map api try link here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - MapView contained within a Listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961275/android-mapview-contained-within-a-listview)

Comment: check this https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/ApiDemos

Answer (score 1):

This may help you. Use it same as image and replace image url with this url and pass you lat/long.

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(activity);

String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=12&size=560x370&markers=size:mid|color:red|"
                        + item.getLattitude()
                        + ","
                        + item.getLongitude()
                        + "&sensor=false";

                aq.id(ImageView).image(url, true, true, 0,
                        0, null, AQuery.FADE_IN);
```