# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Duplicate id 0x7f0d00c0, tag null, with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, listview

I am creating list view which  contain text view,image and  google map.

Code for list view layout:-

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_pic_bg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_time"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView_time"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#0A7692"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_username"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:gravity="left|center"
         android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#BBB9BC"
            android:text=""
        android:textSize="13dp"
         android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
       />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
          android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingRight="3dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customtxtmessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000" />


        <cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:visibility="visible" >
        </cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/customwall_lin_setwatchlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#eef7fa"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customtxtlike"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#D56438" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/customimgdot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dot_sep" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customtxtcomment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Comment"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#D56438" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|right" >



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/customtxttotallikes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/heart_icon"
                android:gravity="center"     
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#D56438" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/customtxttotalcomments"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/comment_icon"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#D56438" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/customlayoutgray"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#a3a8aa"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_temp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#a3a8aa"
            android:textSize="6sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code for List view adapter is:-

```
/********* Adapter class extends with BaseAdapter and implements with OnClickListener ************/
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter   {

         /*********** Declare Used Variables *********/
         private FragmentActivity activity;
         private ArrayList data;
         public ArrayList CommentData;
         private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
         public Resources res;
         CommonWallBean tempValues=null;
         ViewHolder holder;
         int i=0;
         public static  String id="";
         String TextOfLike="";
         SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
         GoogleMap map;

         HashMap<String, String> mMarkerPlaceLink = new HashMap<String, String>();

         Context con;

         /*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
         public CustomAdapter(Context c,FragmentActivity a, ArrayList d,ArrayList CommentData,Resources resLocal) {

                /********** Take passed values **********/
                 activity = a;
                 data=d;
                 res = resLocal;
                 con=c;
                 CommentData=CommentData;

                 /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () ***********/
                  inflater = ( LayoutInflater )activity.
                                              getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         }

         /******** What is the size of Passed Arraylist Size ************/
         public int getCount() {

             if(data.size()<=0)
                 return 1;
             return data.size();
         }

         public Object getItem(int position) {
             return position;
         }

         public long getItemId(int position) {
             return position;
         }

         /********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
         public static class ViewHolder{

             public TextView customtxtmessage, customtxttime,customtxttotallikes,textView_time,textView_username
                            ,text_likes;
             public ViewPager view_pager;
             public ImageView user_image,customimguseravtar;
             public TextView textViewLike,customtxtcomment,customtxttotalcomments;

             public MapView mapView;


         }

         /****** Depends upon data size called for each row , Create each ListView row *****/
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

             View vi = convertView;

             final PagerAdapter adapter;

             if(convertView==null){

                 /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
                 vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wall, null);

                 /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

                 holder = new ViewHolder();
               //  holder.customtxttime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.customtxttime);
                 holder.textView_username=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_username);
                 holder.customimguseravtar=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                 holder.textView_time=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView_time);
                 holder.view_pager=(ViewPager)vi.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
                 holder.textViewLike=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.customtxtlike);
                 holder.customtxtmessage=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.customtxtmessage);
                 holder.customtxttotallikes=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.customtxttotallikes);
                 holder.customtxtcomment=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.customtxtcomment);
                 holder.customtxttotalcomments=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.customtxttotalcomments);

                 mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                 // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
                 map = mapFragment.getMap();


                 // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
                // SupportMapFragment fragment = ( SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);




                 /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
                 vi.setTag( holder );
             }
             else{
                 holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
             }
              if(position<data.size()){

                 /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
//                 tempValues=null;
                 tempValues = ( CommonWallBean ) data.get( position );


                 /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/

                  holder.textView_time.setText( tempValues.getDate());
                  holder.textView_username.setText( tempValues.getEmployeeName());
                  holder.textViewLike.setText(tempValues.getValueOfLike());
                  holder.customtxtmessage.setText(Html.fromHtml(tempValues.getPostMessage()));
                  holder.customtxttotallikes.setText(tempValues.getPostLikeCount());
                  holder.customtxttotalcomments.setText(tempValues.getPostCommentCount());  

                  try {
                    String url = Const.NewbaseurlPhoto + tempValues.getPhotographFileName();
                    System.out.println("Thumbnil Url "+url);
                    Picasso.with(activity).load(url).into(holder.customimguseravtar);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String wallPhotos = tempValues.getWallPhotograph();
                String latitude = tempValues.getLatitude();
                String longitude = tempValues.getLongitude();


                 if (latitude != null && !latitude.isEmpty() && !latitude.equals("null")){


                    holder.view_pager.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    String Latitude = tempValues.getLatitude();
                    String Longitude = tempValues.getLongitude();

                    //map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    // Showing / hiding your current location
                    map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
                    // Enable / Disable zooming controls
                    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
                    // Enable / Disable my location button
                    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                    // Enable / Disable Compass icon
                    map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
                    // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
                    map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
                    // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
                    map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);

                    MapsInitializer.initialize(con);
                    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
                    double lat = Double.valueOf("23.012034");
                    double longi = Double.valueOf("72.510754");
                    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                            new LatLng(lat, longi))
                            .title("Hello Maps");
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                    map.addMarker(marker);

                    //Zoom Particular position
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(lat,
                                    longi)).zoom(12).build();

                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));



                }else {
                    holder.view_pager.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }

     }


             return vi;
         }

    }
  } 
}
```

The Log Cat is :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.vervesys.konnect, PID: 26705
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #178: Error inflating class fragment
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
     at com.vervesys.konnect.adapter.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:130)
     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2013)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1770)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #178: Duplicate id 0x7f0d00c0, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2293)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.o
03-18 16:56:08.410 26705-27435/com.vervesys.konnect D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3139K, 28% free 8554K/11772K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
```

Please help me to solve this issue,  i am not able to figure out what is wrong with this code.

Please help for the same.

Comment: Remove `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` from line 178 of your xml

Comment: in your layout file ; the map fragment; instead of class:"com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" use this
**android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"**

Comment: Tried both your suggestion @antonio and Djphy but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

in this line

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

AND

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

You need have at the end :

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: I have tried with   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

Comment: @vervesystem did you remove xmlns at second line?

Comment: @vervesystem and I recommend to you make Cleanup and Rebuild your project before launch. For the best case you can also remove app from phone.

Comment: yeahh ssh , i have tried by remove line xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" and unistall app from device also , but still getting same result

Comment: Is there any working example for listview with google map in android??

Comment: @vervesystem please read again, that I wrote. You didn't remove xmlns on `LinearLayout` line.

Comment: Did you make cleanup a project?

Comment: yeahh ,Rebuid project again and Reinstall app but still same error

Comment: Looks so strange. I suppose that this a not actual log

Comment: i debug code, application crash when adapter 2 time goes to set lat long

Answer (score 0):

After struggle a lot for this issue, finally i found that google provides static map in URL.

By using Mapview or fragmentManager will be heavy and app will be slow. so for this better option is to use google static map api.

More details are provided in [Android - MapView contained within a Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961275/android-mapview-contained-within-a-listview)  and

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

I posted this answer as it may help other.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this line of code in your adapter class for inflating layout

vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wall, parent,false);